# Check if cell in excel is empty or blank

Tags: excel, vba, cell, is-empty

I have a question about checking cells is empty in Excel VBA. I did it with 0 but don't know how to do it with blank or empty.

Code:

```
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=1000/(IF( RC[-2] = 0,100000000,RC[-2]))"
```

What i want it, if RC[-2] = 0 or empty, then RC[-2]= 100000000, if not then RC[-2]

something like: `"=1000/(IF( OR(RC[-2] = 0, RC[-2]= Empty),100000000,RC[-2]))"` but this code doesn't do it

Comment: i tried it, it is not correct, debug error

Comment: i tried IsEmpty(RC[-2]) but it gived me error #Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Can work for Cell format in TEXT

to serve your requirement:

```
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(RC[-2])),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RC[-2])),VALUE(RC[-2])<>0),1000/VALUE(RC[-2]),0.000001),0.000001)"
```

Comment: I got the same result: `#VALUE!` when the cell is blank

Comment: Can you doublecheck that cell is really blank or if there are some tab/space?

Comment: i tried it, but why do i have always the same result, "VALUE!" `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=((RC[-1]*(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(RC[-2])),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RC[-2])),VALUE(RC[-2])<>0),1000/VALUE(RC[-2]),0.000001),0.000001)))/(1000*R2C3))*100"`

Comment: I think you need to do the same checking for RC[-1] cell's FORMAT is TEXT or not,   same applies to R2C3's FORMAT, let me provide you a VBA solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21258/discussion-between-larry-and-le-viet-hung)

Answer (score 0):

Try with IsEmpty instead of IsBlank.